# Hiding plugin on pages in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a button which displays a like/upvote button. There is an error in the plugin which displays the button on every page of the site. It should only show on blog posts and job listings through WP job manager.

Is there any way to remove this on pages only?

My current solution is:

```
.vortex-container-vote {text-indent: -9999px;}
```

But this removes the plugin from every page(including blog posts and job listings)

I wonder if anybody has a solution which keeps blog posts and listings?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress includes a post-type identifier class in the body tag. So something like this should do it:

```
/* Here you hide it everywhere */
.vortex-container-vote { 
    display: none;
}

/* Then here you only show it on the post-types you want */
.post .vortex-container-vote { 
    display: block;
}
```

Note that this only shows it on posts, as I don't know the post-type for your job listings. But if say the post-type is single-job_listing, then change the second part of the css above to this to include the job listings:

```
.post .vortex-container-vote, .single-job_listing .vortex-container-vote { 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That has worked perfectly! How would I go about finding out the post-type identifier class? The listings I would like to enable the plugin are like this - https://www.marriedin.co.uk/supplier/ge-photography/ I can't find the post-type in the code

Comment: @jthink right click on a jobs page, and select view source. Find the body tag, and either the first or the second will have the post-type. For example my body tag starts `<body class="page page-id-152` - here the first class shows it is a page.

Comment: @jthink Based on your link I believe it's `single-job_listing` - see my updated answer. If it works, please remember to accept this answer by clicking on the tick below the arrows :) thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked great! Very much appreciated